# Where should the relative pronoun be placed in the following example?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which of these two statements is correct?

1. I am writing this for an unethical person I have no intention of making whose name public.
2. I am writing this for an unethical person whose name I have no intention of making public.

I tried many sources but I could not find an answer to this. Is it necessary to place 'whose' right after 'person'?

Comment: No. 1 is ungrammatical. No. 2 is fine.

Comment: @Robusto please add it as answer and also give reasons. I really want to know the reasons.